# Send mail SMTP: Called Mail() without being connected GMAIL

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have tried to send email all forms , changed the doors to 465/587 , already checked the less secure applications account settings , already checked in my hosting is the PHP extensions are active and all this " OK" , already tried send with hotmail account to make sure that the problem was in the code, already traded single quotes with double quotes , already checked the password to make sure that is correct , I have done everything and still keep getting the following message :

> Mail error: The following From address failed: taxcoe@gmail.com :
>   Called Mail() without being connected

Page `enviar.php`

```
<?php
$Nome        = $_POST["Nome"];    // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$assunto        = $_POST["Assunto"];    // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$Email        = $_POST["Email"];    // Pega o valor do campo Email
$Mensagem    = $_POST["Mensagem"];    // Pega os valores do campo Mensagem

// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai         = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nAssunto: $assunto\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";

require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

define('GUSER', 'taxcoe@gmail.com');    // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', '****');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;        // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;        // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';    // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    //$mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->MsgHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 
//o nome do email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

 if (smtpmailer('taxcoe@gmail.com', 'taxcoe@gmail.com', 'Nome do Enviador', 'Contato do Site', $Vai)) {

    Header("location:http://www.pauloroberto.xyz"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

Page `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Email</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>

<body>

<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
    <label for="Nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nome" size="35" />

    <label for="Email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" size="35" />

    <label for="Fone">Assunto:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fone" size="35" />

    <label for="Mensagem">Mensagem:</label>
    <textarea name="Mensagem" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: port 465 is for ssl and port 587 is for tls When you changed the ports, did you also change tls to ssl

Comment: I changed yes tried N settings and unsuccessful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this now I try and get success

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl'; tls
$mail->Host = "hostname"; 
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SetLanguage("tr", "phpmailer/language");
$mail->CharSet  ="utf-8";
$mail->Username = GUSER; 
$mail->Password = GPWD; 
$mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
$mail->AddAddress($para); 
$mail->Subject = "You have Message From Site"; 
$mail->Body = $Vai;
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Mail error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.